# How to maintain session in React Native Apps?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, redux

Can anybody tell me how to maintain session for a user login. For example when the user sign-in to an application they have to be signed in unless the user logouts or uninstall the application.

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with React Native. It's a purely a matter of creating / maintaining a server side session. There are a large number of ways to do this, but the implementation in the app, will depend on your server side solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use AsyncStorage.

Example:

For save:

```
AsyncStorage.multiSet([
    ["email", userInfo.email],
    ["password", userInfo.password]
])
```

For Delete:

```
let keys = ['email', 'password'];
AsyncStorage.multiRemove(keys, (err) => {
    console.log('Local storage user info removed!');
});
```

For Get:

```
AsyncStorage.multiGet(['email', 'password']).then((data) => {
    let email = data[0][1];
    let password = data[1][1];

    if (email !== null)
        //Your logic
});
```

**Important** - password should be encrypted

Answer (score 0):

Normally,there will be a session duration maintained in the server.Like for example say 1 hour.So every time when the app launches,call the login api and create a session.When the user first login,save the email and password in `NSUserDefaults` and whenever the session expires,the next api call will return a session specific error code (say like for example:401 error),Then get the values from `NSUserDefaults` and login automatically.

Also clear the `NSUserDefaults` and all other user related values on logout.

Comment: thanks abhi1992, but i want to know how to use this with react native apps

Comment: This is a terrible idea, never save the user's password like this. You should get a session token or key or something that conveys the auth context that you might want to hold on to.

Comment: If the session is expired then we need to create a new one right?HOw do we do that?